# How to match values to a list of numbers in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have hundreds lists of:
[image]

Is there a faster way to change it to:
[image]

Fill in the count matching the value but with all the consecutive numbers.

Comment: Faster way to change it than what?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can use these formulae:

value: `=SEQUENCE(MAX(A2:A7)+1,,0,1)`
*(enough to enter in first cell, will be autofilled as necessary)*

Count: `=FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=D2,"")`
*(enter in first cell, then fill down)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data in Value column in second image, the formula based on the row number could be helpful.

For example, you need to enter data from 0 to 20 from cell D2, then we could caculate the end cell would be D22.

Then select any cell, enter D2:D22 in Name Box, press Enter key, enter `=Row(A2)-2`, press Ctrl+Enter.

[image]

And then please enter the range in Nambe Box to select the cell range of Count column, such as E2:E22, press Enter.

[image]

Then enter `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$12,2,FALSE),"")` in formula bar.

[image]

At last, press **Ctrl**+**Enter** at the same time.